# Output of VGG Model becomes constant after training and Loss/Accuracy are not improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net, image-classification

I'm trying to implement a slightly smaller version of VGG16 and train it from scratch on a dataset of about 6000 images (5400 for training and 600 for validation). I chose a batch size of 30 so that it can neatly fit within the dataset, otherwise I would get his with IncompatibleShape error during training.

After going through 15-20 epochs, the EarlyStopping callback kicks in and stops the training.

I'm facing two issues with this model

1. After this, when I pass in test images into the model, the output
   seems to remain constant. The least I expect is that for imageA,
   predicted output should be different from imageB. I'm unable to figure out why this is the case
2. Loss and Accuracy seem not to change much. I was expecting that the accuracy would go up at least to about 50% for the number of epochs, but it does not go above 23%. I have tried to include steps_per_epoch, ReduceLROnPlateau but they doesn't seem make any dent.

Training Output:

```
Epoch 1/50
180/180 [==============================] - 50s 278ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1987 - val_loss: 1.6109 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1267

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 1.61094, saving model to vgg16.h5
Epoch 2/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 285ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2044 - val_loss: 1.6107 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2133

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 1.61094 to 1.61067, saving model to vgg16.h5
Epoch 3/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 285ms/step - loss: 1.6098 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1946 - val_loss: 1.6106 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1400

Epoch 00003: val_loss improved from 1.61067 to 1.61059, saving model to vgg16.h5
Epoch 4/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1928 - val_loss: 1.6098 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2000

Epoch 00004: val_loss improved from 1.61059 to 1.60983, saving model to vgg16.h5

Epoch 00004: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 2.5000001187436283e-05.
Epoch 5/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6093 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2033 - val_loss: 1.6103 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1467

Epoch 00005: val_loss did not improve from 1.60983
Epoch 6/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6094 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1989 - val_loss: 1.6106 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1400

Epoch 00006: val_loss did not improve from 1.60983
Epoch 7/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6094 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2069 - val_loss: 1.6098 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1733

Epoch 00007: val_loss improved from 1.60983 to 1.60978, saving model to vgg16.h5

Epoch 00007: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 1e-05.
Epoch 8/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6093 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2076 - val_loss: 1.6103 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1600

Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 1.60978
Epoch 9/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2006 - val_loss: 1.6097 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2200

Epoch 00009: val_loss improved from 1.60978 to 1.60975, saving model to vgg16.h5
Epoch 10/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 287ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2043 - val_loss: 1.6101 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1667

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 11/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6094 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2009 - val_loss: 1.6102 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1800

Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 12/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2041 - val_loss: 1.6115 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1600

Epoch 00012: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 13/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1989 - val_loss: 1.6108 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1867

Epoch 00013: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 14/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6094 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2009 - val_loss: 1.6102 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1733

Epoch 00014: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 15/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6093 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2074 - val_loss: 1.6113 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1467

Epoch 00015: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 16/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6098 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1983 - val_loss: 1.6105 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1867

Epoch 00016: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 17/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2056 - val_loss: 1.6119 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1667

Epoch 00017: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 18/50
180/180 [==============================] - 52s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6093 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1994 - val_loss: 1.6110 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1800

Epoch 00018: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Epoch 19/50
180/180 [==============================] - 51s 286ms/step - loss: 1.6095 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2026 - val_loss: 1.6103 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1667

Epoch 00019: val_loss did not improve from 1.60975
Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch.
Epoch 00019: early stopping
```

Code used to get Predictions:

```
predictions = []
actuals=[]

for i, (images, labels) in enumerate( test_datasource):
  if i > 2:
    break
  pred = model_2(images)
  print(labels.shape, pred.shape)
  for j in range(len(labels)):
    actuals.append( labels[j])
    predictions.append(pred[j])
    print(labels[j].numpy(), "\t", pred[j].numpy())
```

Output of the above code:

```
(30, 5) (30, 5)
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
(30, 5) (30, 5)
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
(30, 5) (30, 5)
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]     [0.19907779 0.20320047 0.1968051  0.20173152 0.19918515]
```

Here is the model summary:

```
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(30, 224, 224, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_1_1 (Conv2D)            (30, 224, 224, 32)        896       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_1_2 (Conv2D)            (30, 224, 224, 32)        9248      
_________________________________________________________________
maxpool_1 (MaxPooling2D)     (30, 112, 112, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_2_1 (Conv2D)            (30, 112, 112, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
conv_2_2 (Conv2D)            (30, 112, 112, 64)        36928     
_________________________________________________________________
maxpool_2 (MaxPooling2D)     (30, 56, 56, 64)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_3_1 (Conv2D)            (30, 56, 56, 128)         73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv_3_2 (Conv2D)            (30, 56, 56, 128)         147584    
_________________________________________________________________
conv_3_3 (Conv2D)            (30, 56, 56, 128)         147584    
_________________________________________________________________
maxpool_3 (MaxPooling2D)     (30, 28, 28, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_4_1 (Conv2D)            (30, 28, 28, 256)         295168    
_________________________________________________________________
conv_4_2 (Conv2D)            (30, 28, 28, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv_4_3 (Conv2D)            (30, 28, 28, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
maxpool_4 (MaxPooling2D)     (30, 14, 14, 256)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_5_1 (Conv2D)            (30, 14, 14, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv_5_2 (Conv2D)            (30, 14, 14, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
conv_5_3 (Conv2D)            (30, 14, 14, 256)         590080    
_________________________________________________________________
maxpool_5 (MaxPooling2D)     (30, 7, 7, 256)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (30, 12544)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc_1 (Dense)                 (30, 4096)                51384320  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (30, 4096)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc_2 (Dense)                 (30, 4096)                16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (30, 4096)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (30, 5)                   20485     
=================================================================
Total params: 71,866,277
Trainable params: 71,866,277
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The code is here in Google Colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AWe87Zb3MvF90j3RS7sv3OiSgR86q4j_

I tried two versions of VGG-16, one with half the depth of filters than the original and the second with quarter of the depth of filters.

Comment: seems like even your training loss is not improving after each epoch while training its almost same after each epoch, please check the training pipeline again, or please mention the training pipeline here for others to see

Comment: By training pipeline, do you mean output of model.summary? Sorry, I'm still learning the jargons of the field

Comment: sorry didnt notice that you have already provided google colab link

Comment: can you try increasing your learning rate, and also check your loss function is getting correct input which it expects, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy

Comment: I am converting the labels into one-hot encoded vectors using label_mode='categorical' while loading data. the labels are indeed generated this way, as can be seen above where I compare the labels with the predicted outputs.  CategoricalCrossEntropy seems to be the loss that is generally used in scenarios of one-hot encoded. Is there any other reason why you are asking to check the loss function? I will try to increase the learning rate now. will add comment once I'm done

Comment: yes thats right just wanted to confirm as was trying to think what could be the reason for it

Comment: can you try increasing the learning rate too

Comment: Running it now. Will post update in about 20-30 minutes

Comment: No luck, the loss is getting stuck at nan. Tried adam (0.1, 0.05, 0.01) and SGD(0.1)

Comment: I take the last comment back. I did not reinitialize the model, so that weights were not put back to their random values. Let me do that and re-post again. Sorry about that

Comment: After reinitializing the model and running it with adam (0.1, 0.05) and SGD (0.1, 0.2), the loss and accuracy are behaving the same way.

Comment: training loss didnt change in successive epochs?

Comment: Not by much. From 1.610n to 1.5983

Comment: I ran a prediction on test data on the model without training (random weights). I see that the predicted output does change. The training cycles seem to fix the output to a constant value. Now even I'm doubting that the loss function is teaching the model to go constant.

Comment: Found few articles on the getting constant output. Turns out that my learning rate was too high, causing high gradients resulting in Relus dying and in turn causing the outputs to get fixed and never change from their fixed state during training. I'm running the training right now with the modifications and will post an update as soon as I'm done

Answer (score 2):

I was under the impression that the issue was that the loss and accuracy were unchanging and that is why, when using the model for predictions the outputs were fixed and unchanging irrespective of the inputs being fed to it.

When I reinitialized the model by calling the Model(inputs...,outputs...) function, and passed inputs to it without training, the outputs were at least changing.

I tried with multiple learning rates and optimizers with no change in behavior of the model.

After some more google searching I chanced upon these articles:

1. https://www.quora.com/Why-does-my-convolutional-neural-network-always-produce-the-same-outputs
2. https://www.quora.com/Why-does-my-own-neural-network-give-me-the-same-output-for-different-input-sets
3. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5706/what-is-the-dying-relu-problem-in-neural-networks

I made two changes in the code to get it to finally work.

1. I was initially only dividing the image array by 255 to get the values to fall between 0 and 1 followed by subtracting 0.5 from the result to cause the values to fall between -0.5 to 0.5. This was changed to the use of tf.image.per_image_standardization(images-127) and dividing the result by the maximum value in each image. As a result the image values fell between -1 and +1
2. Another major cause of fixed outputs is the model's relu units dying (or saturating) during training. relu activation function inherently has this problem where once a variable's weight goes to 0, it does not recover from it. Although high learning rate is said to cause this problem, I was unable to find a learning rate that alleviated from this issue. Another solution is to change the activation function to leaky relu or elu (Exponential relu) which have an inherent mechanism to recover from this issue

With these changes, the model's loss dropped to < 1 and training-accuracy <0.90 although validation numbers were not this good, but certainly better than before